# Как в Task использовать Элементы из панели?

Tags: c#, tpl

Есть `Task` внутри идет цикл и при каждой итерации нужно вывести данные в `TextBox`.
Пишу так

```
Task.Run(() => {
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      txtBox.text = "Example: " + i;
   }
},TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext);
```

пишет что был создан не из того потока. как быть? Нигде норм не могу прочесть про это. кто сталкивался помогите.

Answer (score 2):

Тебе нужно использовать метод Invoke у textBox.

> Invoke - Выполняет указанный делегат в том потоке, которому принадлежит базовый дескриптор окна элемента управления

```
Task.Run(() => {
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      txtBox.invoke(new Action(()=>{textBox.text = "Example: " + i;}))
    }
},TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext);
```

**UPDATE**

WinForm - txtBox.invoke

WPF - txtBox.Dispatcher.Invoke

Comment: Работает. А правильно ли так использовать это?

Comment: Метод Task.Run() ставит задачу в в очередь для запуска в ThreadPool. Иными словами твоя задача будет выполнена в другом потоке (можешь это проверить написав MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId) перед Task.Run и внутри Task.Run). Другой поток просто не догадывается о существовании textbox`a, следовательно тебе нужно выполнить действие в потоке который создал textbox.

Comment: Все понял. Спасибо